# How can I access iframe variables from a Svelte app inside it?

Tags: variables, iframe, svelte

I have an iframe that load different svelte app on request.
I need to access the variables defined in the document that contains the iframe, from the svelte app loaded inside it.
Is it possible to act this way?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. Unless the current document and the iframe source share the same origin, JS is not allowed to access the content of the iframe.

It is possible to use [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) from within the frame document and listen to the `message` event on the outside. It is also possible to send messages into the frame using the same mechanism (see linked docs for more info). This way it is possible to communicate across the frame boundary.

An important warning:

> Any window may access this method on any other window, at any time, regardless of the location of the document in the window, to send it a message. Consequently, any event listener used to receive messages **must** first check the identity of the sender of the message, using the `origin` and possibly `source` properties.